# How should I use JSDoc to document DOM events in my design pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have a custom-built JavaScript framework that I inherited from the person that worked here before me. What I can say is that it's a web app of sorts that leverages jQuery.

There are a lot of events being fired by various objects that I'd like to document, but I'm unsure of how to do this. I've seen [JSDoc 3's examples on the @listens page](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-listens.html), but they seem to be oriented more towards a module development pattern, so I'm unsure of how to apply them to the pattern here:

ClassA.js:

```
var ClassA = function (args) {
    //constructor stuff goes here... usually punctuated with:
    this.listenForEvents();
};

ClassA.prototype.listenForEvents = function () {
    $(document).on("someEvent", function (e, args) {
        //Event handlers are almost always anonymous and call class methods,
        //usually to determine if the event needs to be handled by a specific
        //instance of the class, or meeting a criteria. e.g.:
        if (this.identifier === args.identifier) {
            this.someClassMethod(args);
        }
    }.bind(this));
};

ClassA.prototype.someClassMethod = function (args) {
    //handle the event
};
```

ClassB.js:

```
var ClassB = function (args) {
    //constructor stuff goes here...
};

ClassB.prototype.doAThing = function () {
    //code goes here
    $(document).trigger('someEvent', { identifier: 'someIdentifier', aValue: 1, anotherValue: 'two' });
};
```

How/where do I use the `@event`, `@listens`, and `@fires` doclets with this design pattern?